# Rails3+Devise+simple_form+nested_model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, devise, nested, simple-form

I am using devise to authenticate Users, and when new User signs up, I would like to create new Account as well, and set this user as owner of the account. I decided to use form with nested model for this. This is my setup:

models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  has_one :owned_account, :class=> Account, :foreign_key => :owner_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owned_account
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  belongs_to :owner, :class => User, :foreign_key => :owner_id
end
```

routes:

```
devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'authentication', :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
resources :accounts
```

overriden devise registration controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
   def new
     super
     owned_account = resource.build_owned_account
   end

   def create
     super
   end
end
```

form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email, :required => true, :autofocus => true %>
    <%= f.input :password, :required => true %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true %>

    <%= f.simple_fields_for :owned_account do |account| %>
      <%= account.input :name, :required => true %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

No exception is thrown when I access sign_up path, but nested part of the form is not generated. There is a couple of similar questions already, but provided solutions don't seem to work for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with using `super` in overriden controller. 
This code works:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
   def new
      resource = build_resource({})
      resource.build_owned_account
      respond_with resource
   end

   def create
     super
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code:

```
def new
  super
  owned_account = resource.build_owned_account 
end
```

The variable owned_account is not accessible in your view. How about replacing that line with:

```
resource.owned_account = resource.build_owned_account
```